# Prepopulating dropdown options as object using reactive-form dynamically on load

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

While using mat-select in reactive form, when we want to set some option(which is object) as default dynamically for formControl 'skillOptions'. It is not showing the selected value.

Preview here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-evtdwq

Comment: please describe precisely the problem you having. Need more details.

Comment: Why not bind the `value` instead of an object? like `[value]="option.value"`?

Answer (score 1):

Your question statement is rather vague, but from what I can infer, you want your mat-select to display the specified selected options on init. You should be binding `option.value` instead of the entire `option` object to `value`.

In the very first place, you are not able to bind objects to the select-option `value` attribute

```
<form [formGroup]="skillForm">
  <mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Select an option</mat-label>
  <mat-select formControlName="skillOptions">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.value">{{ option.label}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
</form>
```

It should be working on this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h9u3k4?file=src/app/app.component.html).